# insert multi value with SP

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables.

1- student table & 2- Score table

I want to insert value at student table & insert multi value at Score table with SP to SQL Server 2008.

for EX:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertIntoScore]
(
@DateReg datetime,
@stdLastName nvarchar(50),
@stdFirstName nvarchar(50),
@Description nvarchar(500),

multi value as score table...
)
AS
DECLARE @Id AS INT
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Student(DateReg,stdLastName,stdFirstName,[Description])
    VALUES (@DateReg,@stdLastName,@stdFirstName,@Description)
set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

    insert multi value at Score table...    
COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Create a Sql Type for the table you will pass in

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ScoreType AS TABLE ( ScoreID int, StudentID int, etc.... )
```

pass your datatable from C# code into the stored procedure using the above defined type

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertIntoScore] 
( @DateReg datetime, @stdLastName nvarchar(50), @stdFirstName nvarchar(50), 
@Description nvarchar(500),  @tvpScore ScoreType) 
AS 
   .....
   INSERT INTO dbo.Score (ScoreID, StudentID, ....)     
   SELECT dt.ScoreID, @id, .... FROM @tvpScore AS dt;
```

in c# pass the datatable in this way

```
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertIntoScore", sqlConnection); 
SqlParameter p1 = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpScore", dtScore); 
p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 
p1.TypeName = "dbo.ScoreType"; 
.....
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i can not use the ScoreType in @tvpScore ScoreType. Where should I write this code? CREATE TYPE dbo.ScoreType...

Comment: You create it in your SqlServer where you plan to insert your data. Use Sql Server Management Studio. And remember to define all the field of the table you plan to pass to the stored procedure.